# Regex use in Laravel

Tags: php, regex

This is my Laravel code:

```
$validator = \Validator::make($val, [
                    'service_activity' => 'required|max:1000',
                    'inspired' => 'required',
                    'obstacles' => 'required|max:1000',
                    'working_on_acitivity' =>  array('required', 'regex:^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$'),
                    'spend_time' => 'required',
                    'activity_impact' => 'required|max:1000',
                    'fund_raising' => 'required',
                    'raised_amount' => 'required|numeric',
                    'people_involved' => 'required|numeric',
                    'learned_from_experience' => 'required|max:1000',
                ],$messages);
```

I want to use the regex for the field in `working_on_acitivity` but always getting the same error. I have used the regex in an array as given in the Laravel documentation:

> type":"ErrorException","message":"preg_match(): No ending delimiter '^' found

Comment: Maybe so - add 2 slashes `'regex:/^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$/'` ?

Comment: You need to add delimiters around the pattern (for example `/`). As an aside: `'working_on_acitivity'` => `'working_on_activity'`

Comment: Hi there. It looks like you are writing all your titles in lower case. As editors read your questions, the mistakes are likely to be improved over time, so if you can use caps at the start of the title, and for brand names like Laravel, that will save some future effort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
'regex:^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$'
```

to

```
'regex:#^(1[0-2]|0[1-9]|\d)\/(20\d{2}|19\d{2}|0(?!0)\d|[1-9]\d)$#'
```

using `#` as delimiter.
(This is based on your error message talking about missing delimiters.)